# Почему при выводе на печать не срабатывают стили css?

Tags: javascript, print

Проблема в том, что от сюда `http://site.ru/css/table.css` не беруться стили для формирования печати. Как это можно исправить?

```js
function CallPrint(strid) {
  var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
  var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=50,top=50,width=800,height =640,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
  var prtCSS = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.ru/css/table.css">';
  var print = document.createElement("div");
  print.className = "contentpane";
  print.setAttribute("id", "print");
  print.appendChild(prtContent.cloneNode(true));

  WinPrint.document.body.appendChild(print);

  WinPrint.focus();
  WinPrint.print();
  WinPrint.close();
}
```

```html
<div id="print-content">
  <div id="myTable">
    <table class="one">11-24-34-35-8
      <table class="two">3</table>
    </table>
  </div><a onClick="javascript:CallPrint('print-content');" title="Распечатать проект">Распечатать</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы присваиваете переменной var prtCSS  значение линка на ксс файл и больше эту переменную не используете.
Используйте явное объявление стилей на странице через:

```
<style>
@media print {
    /* здесь будут стили для печати */
    body {
        font-size: 28px;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Попробовал, не сработало, к сожалению